# Avoid Service locator in strategy design pattern

Tags: java, php, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, service-locator

Take a look on that pseudocode

```
class A,B,C implements StrategyInterface
{
    private dep;

    constructor(Dep dep) {
        this->dep = dep;    
    }
}

class StrategyResolver
{
    private locator;

    constructor(ServiceLocator locator) {
        this->locator = locator;
    }
    
    public function resolve(data): StrategyInterface
    {
        if ( xxx ) {
            return locator->get(A);
        } else if ( yyy ) {
            return locator->get(B);
        }
        return locator->get(C);
    }
}
```

As service locator is considered as anti pattern, how to avoid it in this case? `A,B,C` can have various dependencies, thats why I would like to instantiate it using all benefits of dependency injections. I could albo inject `A,B,C` as dependencies of `StrategyResolver`, but what if I have there like 10 strategies. The `StrategyResolver` dependency list is then too long.

Comment: symfony (for PHP) has a DI system which allows to name the services and pass an array as input of a class declaring the items of the list one by one. Docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html
Let me know if this might solve the problem, then I might write the answer with a whole working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring you can inject all known beans of a certain type automatically:

```
private final List<StrategyInterface> strategies;

public StrategyResolver(List<StrategyInterface> strategies) {
    this.strategies = strategies;
}
```

If this is the only constructor Spring will have no trouble injecting all the beans implementing the StrategyInterface. Of course those beans need to be known to Spring using for example the @Named annotation on the class:

```
@javax.inject.Named
public class A implements StrategyInterface {
```

BTW why not just name the interface 'Strategy'? The 'Interface' suffix does not really add anything.

EDIT: to determine which Strategy applies you can add a method to the Strategy interface:

```
@javax.inject.Named
public class A implements StrategyInterface {

    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(String data) {
        // just an example
        return "xxx".equals(data);
    }
```

In the StrategyResolver you would have code like this:

```
public StrategyInterface resolve(String data) {
    for(StrategyInterface strategy : strategies) {
        if (strategy.appliesTo(data)) {
            return strategy;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No strategy applies to " + data);
}
```

Or in more recent style:

```
public StrategyInterface resolve(String data) {
    return strategies.stream().filter(s -> s.appliesTo(data)).findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No strategy applies to " + data));
}
```

One gotcha here is that to avoid the exception above you must ensure that a strategy always applies. You could create a 'DefaultStrategy' which always applies and is added as the last strategy in the list, e.g:

```
private final List<StrategyInterface> strategies;

public StrategyResolver(List<StrategyInterface> strategies, DefaultStrategy defaultStrategy) {
    this.strategies = new ArrayList<>(strategies);    
    this.strategies.add(defaultStrategy);
}
```

Comment: I thought about list of dependencies, but when I have that list how do I get which strategy from that list fits my conditions?
I write mainly in PHP, there is naming convention https://www.php-fig.org/bylaws/psr-naming-conventions/ which I follow.

Comment: I usually add a method to the interface which can determine if the strategy applies. So your list of conditions xxx, yyy would each go into the strategy implementation it belongs to, inside that determining method.